# start-stop-daemon does not start java process

Tags: java, jenkins, start-stop-daemon

I am trying to execute this script with the "start" option:

```
#!/bin/sh

DESC="Jenkins CI Server"
NAME=jenkins
PIDFILE=$NAME.pid
RUN_AS=alex
COMMAND="/usr/bin/java"
COMMAND_ARGS="-jar jenkins.war"

d_start() {
    start-stop-daemon --start --verbose --background --make-pidfile --pidfile "$PIDFILE" --chuid "$RUN_AS" --exec "$COMMAND" -- $COMMAND_ARGS
}

d_stop() {
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE
    if [ -e $PIDFILE ]
        then rm $PIDFILE
    fi
}

case $1 in
    start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: $NAME"
    d_start
    echo "."
    ;;
    stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $DESC: $NAME"
    d_stop
    echo "."
    ;;
    restart)
    echo -n "Restarting $DESC: $NAME"
    d_stop
    sleep 1
    d_start
    echo "."
    ;;
    *)
    echo "usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

It creates the pid file in the current directory, however I cannot find the process using:

```
ps -ef | grep java
```

The process does not exist. The stop command also complains regarding the missing process.

I am just trying to follow instructions for [Starting and Accessing Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) .

Comment: Take a look in the Jenkins logs. it sounds like the process starts OK but then fails because of an error. Try /var/log/jenkins

Comment: There is no folder named /var/log/jenkins. When running "java -jar jenkins.war" command, the output is thrown directly to console, but when running the same command with start-stop-daemon, no logs are generated on console, nor in "/var/log/jenkins" and neither in "~/.jenkins".

Comment: @Mark Chorley I understand the logs are the key in solving this, but I have no clue how to generate them. This page (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins) does not say how to generate logs when running the command with start-stop-daemon.

Comment: First try java -jar jenkins.war > /var/log/jenkins 2>&1. That should start jenkins and send logs to /var/log/jenkins. Fix whatever errors you see  there and then try it as a service.

Comment: @Mark Chorley "java -jar jenkins.war > /var/log/jenkins 2>&1" works perfectly. I can access "http://localhost:8080/". But the problem is when I start it using "start-stop-daemon".

Comment: Are you running that as the 'alex' user? If so add the > /var/log/jenkins 2>&1 to the start-stop-daemon script. Also check any logging from start-stop-daemon itself